# PermissionError Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, html, permissions

I am trying to read a directory which contains html files with python. The code I am using is this:

```
    import os
f = open(r"C:\Users\Grty\Desktop\de", "w+")
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  content = f.read()
  print (filename, len(content))
```

The problem is I cant access the directory. I have tried different locations but the problem persists. I have also done the relative chmod 777 (Using windows 10) and still nothing. I enabled sharing with everyone, giving read/write permissions to everyone and also disabled the "read only" (which somehow is being re-enabled itself). I have also run the cmd as an admin and still no progress. Anyone got an idea of how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open a folder for writing:

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\Grty\Desktop\de", "w+")
```

But this is a folder, which can't be opened using `open()` even in `"r"` mode, because it isn't a file, and if you try, Windows will say *access denied*. As you get each `filename`, open that:

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.read()
```

Comment: The fact it's a windows filesystem is mostly irrelevant - you cannot `open()` a directory in Linux either (but the error message is more accurate: "[Errno 21] Is a directory")