# Unable to progress past signup due to media_root permission error

Tags: django

I'm attempting to signup for an account on my django site, but I'm running into the following error:

```
Thumbnail generation failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\versatileimagefield\image_warmer.py", line 117, in _prewarm_versatileimagefield
    url = get_url_from_image_key(versatileimagefieldfile, size_key)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\versatileimagefield\utils.py", line 216, in get_url_from_image_key
    img_url = img_url[size_key].url
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\versatileimagefield\datastructures\sizedimage.py", line 149, in __getitem__
    height=height
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\versatileimagefield\datastructures\sizedimage.py", line 201, in create_resized_image
    path_to_image
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\versatileimagefield\datastructures\base.py", line 140, in retrieve_image
    image = self.storage.open(path_to_image, 'rb')
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 33, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 218, in _open
    return File(open(self.path(name), mode))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\staticfiles\\media_root'
```

I just reinstalled windows 10 while keeping personal files. This error never happened before reinstalling windows 10. I've looked at the folder permissions and can't see anything amiss. Any thoughts on what I can check?

Thanks!

Comment: When I run command prompt as adminstrator before running the command 'python manage.py runserver', I don't have this problem.

Comment: How you are getting the thumbnail. Show that.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759182/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied