# How to get the win32 handle of a directory in Python?

Tags: python, windows

You can get the win32 handle of a file in Python by:

```
file = CreateFile("C:\\File.txt")
handle = str(msvcrt.get_osfhandle(file.fileno()))
file.close()
```

However to do this you need to make a file object, which cannot be a directory. For example,

```
dir = CreateFile("C:\\Directory")
handle = str(msvcrt.get_osfhandle(file.fileno()))
dir.close()
```

This throws an error because 'C:\Directory' is a directory:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Directory'`
See: [PermissionError Errno 13 Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759182/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

How could you do this or something like this for a directory?

Comment: According to the [official MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-a-handle-to-a-directory), `To obtain a handle to an existing directory, call the CreateFile function with the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag.`. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @RandomDavis I think that is a C++ function, I am looking for a Python solution

Comment: The solution should still be the same, since you're calling just a wrapper of that function.

Comment: @RandomDavis Oh ok, how do I do that?

Comment: By putting `flagsAndAttributes=FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` in the function call? How else?

Comment: @RandomDavis I meant like how do you call a wrapper of a C++ function

Comment: By calling `CreateFile()` you're already doing that. That's how Python lets you call those Windows functions.

Comment: @RandomDavis Oh sorry I'm kind of new to Python, my bad

Comment: `CreateFile` returns an OS handle. Do not call `get_osfhandle`, which gets the OS handle for a C file descriptor.

Comment: Without invoking backup semantics, another option to open a directory, if the filesystem supports NT file streams (e.g. NTFS, ReFS), is to explicitly open the index stream of the directory, which even works with `os.open`, e.g. `fd = os.open('C:/Directory::$INDEX_ALLOCATION', 0);` `h = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(fd)`. The system drive "C:" is required to be an NTFS filesystem, but a path on "C:" could also be a mountpoint for a filesystem that lacks stream support, so there's no guarantee that this will work.

Comment: The Universal CRT (as used by Python 3.5+) supports an undocumented flag to use backup semantics (0x2000), so can also use `fd = os.open('C:/Directory', 0x2000);` `h = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(fd)`. Of course anything that's undocumented is free to change in a future release, so relying on this is dubious.